# Is there a transformation that could inverse the residuals in multiple OLS regression?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, least-squares, residuals

Let's say I have a partial residual plot that looks like this, where the residuals are predicted minus actuals.

[image: Original Partial Residual Plot]

I would instead prefer for the residuals to be inversed, so that instead of underpredicting the outliers at extreme X values, we overpredict the outliers.  I think Log transformation works somewhat but the first one looks like a better fit in general, given there isn't much of a pattern in the partial residual plot.  The reason I want to over predict extreme values is because for this use case, it would be more conservative at the tails, which is what I want.

[image: Log Partial Residual Plot]

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you asking about how to fit a new model that is less likely to underpredict outliers? It sounds like you want a model that is more sensitive to outliers (which is quite unusual). Maybe quantile regression or a regression that minimizes the L4 norm of the residuals instead of the L2 norm. Remember that regression models don't predict outcome data points, they predict the *mean* of the outcome at a combination of predictor values.

Comment: Yeah, so I need a way to just inverse the outliers.  So model doesn't have to be more or less sensitive to outliers, rather just needs to over predict values at extreme ranges.  So in my second residual plot, you can see that at low and high X values, my model predictions tend to be much higher than actuals, which is what I want.  In the original one, my model predictions tend to be lower than actuals, which is what I don't want.  Only issue with second plot is, the residuals have a shape to them when the first doesn't.

Comment: Ideally, i'd get a perfect fit where conditional distributions of Y given X is normal, but since my data isn't really normal, I'd prefer to skew one direction as opposed to the other.  Because once the model gets implemented IRL, i'd prefer to over predict the tails (as those tend to be more risky) which in my use case would, result in conservative predictions, which is exactly what I want.  I don't want to under predict the tails.  And the model needs to be simple enough to implement within our framework, so I'm limited to basic regression techniques.